# Grails data binding field exclusion

Tags: grails, data-binding

I am using Grails 2.5 and use Grails databinding in request methods.
For a basic example of the situation consider the following:

**Domain class**

```
class Product {
  String field1
  String privateField
}
```

**Controller**

```
class ProductController {
  def update(Product productInstance) {
     productInstance.save()
  }
}
```

If I pass an existing Product to the controller like

```
{"id":3, "privateField":"newValue","field1":"whatever"}
```

the old value of `privateField` is overwritten. I want to enforce, that `privateField` is never bound from a request and avoid checking if the field is dirty.
Is there a mechanism in Grails to achieve this?

If I have to do the dirty check, how can I discard the new value and use the old one?

Comment: Just a guess, would "final" work?   Seems like the setter wouldn't generate, so it wouldn't bind?

Comment: I still want to be able to modify the field programmatically, I just won't to prevent binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure there's a "bindable" constraint.
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/ref/Constraints/bindable.html

```
class Product {
  String field1
  String privateField

  static constraints = {
      privateField bindable: false
  }
}
```

Should keep that field from binding automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce which values are bound, but you'll need to change your method signature to get more control of the [data binding](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/ref/Controllers/bindData.html) process.

```
class ProductController {
  def update() {
     def productInstance = Product.get(params.id)

     bindData(productInstance, params, [exclude: ['privateField']]
     productInstance.save()
  }
}
```